# How to obtain a request token from Twitter using OAuth and NSURLRequest?

Tags: objective-c, twitter, oauth

I am trying to obtain and request token from twitter with this code:

```
NSString *letters = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
int length = 42;
NSMutableString *nonce = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity: length];
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    [nonce appendFormat: @"%C", [letters characterAtIndex: arc4random() % [letters length]]];
}

NSURL *requestTokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"];
NSInteger numberOfSecs = round([[NSDate date]timeIntervalSince1970]);
NSString *timestampString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", numberOfSecs];

NSMutableDictionary *signingParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithCapacity:10];
[signingParams setObject:@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" forKey:@"oauth_consumer_key"];
[signingParams setObject:[nonce copy] forKey:@"oauth_nonce"];
[signingParams setObject:@"HMAC-SHA1" forKey:@"oauth_signature_method"];
[signingParams setObject:timestampString forKey:@"oauth_timestamp"];
[signingParams setObject:@"1.0" forKey:@"oauth_version"];

NSMutableURLRequest *mURLRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:requestTokenURL];
mURLRequest.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
NSString *callbackURLString = @"http://bytolution.com";
//that is one fat piece of code...
NSString *authenticationHeaderString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"OAuth oauth_callback=\"%@\", oauth_nonce=\"%@\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"%@\", oauth_consumer_key=\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\", oauth_signature=\"%@\", oauth_version=\"1.0\"", [callbackURLString URLEncodedString], nonce, timestampString, [BYOAuthSignatureString signatureStringWithParameters:signingParams URL:[mURLRequest.URL absoluteString] HTTPMethod:mURLRequest.HTTPMethod]];

[mURLRequest setValue:authenticationHeaderString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];


NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse;
NSError *error;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:mURLRequest returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];
NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"data: %@, response:%@, error: %@", dataString , urlResponse.allHeaderFields, error);
```

The class `BYOAuthSignatureString` creates the signature to sign the request and I checked all the parameters for the request. They should work according to Twitter's documentation.

[Creating a signature](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature)

[Implementing Sign-in with Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter)

But my loggings say

`data: Failed to validate oauth signature and token, response:(null), error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0x20892200 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token, NSUnderlyingError=0x20891ac0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1012.)"}`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you can get away with just using the user's Twitter account the system provices, you might want to look at Apple's Social and Accounts frameworks, which deal with all of this for you.

Comment: @JesseRusak I already used and learned to hate them...

Comment: Thanks for sharing your service URL and Twitter OAuth key with everybody on StackOverflow.

Comment: OK. Well, in that case, you might want to try our your code against this test server: http://term.ie/oauth/example/

Comment: @JesseRusak Thank you soooo much for this little hint! The server returns things like the *right* base string for creating the signature. Already spotted a few mistakes... Maybe you want to post your comment as an answer, as it would be more visible and I could upvote it :D

Comment: See my answer over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913491/how-to-make-nsurlrequest-to-obtain-a-twitter-request-token/16545171#16545171

Comment: @Dario whats wrong with the code, as i am following your approach it would be so nice if you share your mistakes...thanks